# PHP Count round thousand to a K style count Facebook Share

Tags: php, facebook

I have a PHP code for the counter but I need to add something to the counter is as follows:

- 1k
- 1100k
- 1200k etc
- 2k
- 2100k etc.
  and
- 2m
- 2500m

For now I have this counter done in PHP.

```
<?php function get_likes($url) {
  $json_string = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url);
  $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
  return intval( $json[$url]['shares'] );
}?>
```

Show with

```
<?php echo get_likes(http://url...); ?>
```

Comment: Any particular question?

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the value into this simple function:

```
function kilomega( $val ) {
    if( $val < 1000 ) return $val;
    $val = (int)($val/1000);
    if( $val < 1000 ) return "${val}k";
    $val = (int)($val/1000);
    return "${val}m";
}
```

Comment: I think @paddy code is much cleaner and nicer i'd use his though you wiil want to round these values at somepoint aswell

Answer (score 0):

instead of show with just echo, check the size so :

```
<?php
 $num_likes = get_likes(http://url...); 
 if($num_likes < 1000){
   echo num_likes;
 }elseif($num_likes > 100000 ){
    echo $num_likes/100000 + "M";
 }else{
    echo $num_likes/1000 + "K";
 }

?>
```

... your probably also going to want to round these values to some precision 1.1k instead of actual 1.117k for example here a link to php doc's to round to the precision you want [rounding in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)